# Character table for the affine group of Z/p^nZ

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, rt.representation-theory

Initial caveat: the following question could probably be answered by Google, MathSciNet or my library, if I could find the right search terms or book... but I've not had any luck today, so I hope someone can point me to a reference.

(The question is related to some of my older questions concerning characters of finite groups. All representations/characters are over the complex field.)

I am trying to estimate a certain invariant associated to finite groups, and recently thought that a useful toy example to play with would be
$$  G = \left\{
\left( \begin{matrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{matrix} \right) \;\mid\;
  a,b\in {\mathbb Z}/p^n{\mathbb Z}, p \nmid a
 \right\} $$
where $p$ is a prime and $n\geq 1$. I guess this might be called the "affine group" of the ring $R={\mathbb Z}/p^n{\mathbb Z}$?

Now the invariant can be calculated pretty easily (modulo tedious sums) once we know the character table of $G$, but this means more than knowing the degrees of the irreducible characters; I need to know the values they take on the various conjugacy classes inside $G$.

For $n=1$ this does not take long to do directly and can also be found as an example in various introductory-level textbooks on representation theory. However, for $n=2$ the best I could find was a section in a paper of several authors, where they just work out the character table by hand after first finding the characters via induction ($G$ is a semi-direct product arising from the action of the group of units in $R$ on the additive group of $R$). Now since I want to continue to higher $n$, I seem to be faced with three options:

1) Slog through the computation myself (which is probably good for my mathematical soul, but takes time & brainpower I need to spend on other things)

2) Learn how to ask a computer to do this (see previous parenthetical remark)

3) Find a reference which just gives the table.

So before embarking on 1), I thought I'd ask here. Most sources I could find from a crude skim online and in my library only discussed linear groups over finite fields; but I'm hoping that the construction here is sufficiently natural that it might have been treated already and written up somewhere.

Comment: Do what's good for your soul, is my advice. Work out the representations, not just the characters.

Comment: I see Denis has changed my \nmid to \not\mid -- which one works better, in people's experience? (When I was typing this question, \not\mid gave a rather ugly result.)

Comment: @Yemon: The \not\mid looked terrible to me.  So, **being bold** (wait, that's not our motto! but anyway) I changed it back to \nmid to see what that looks like.  My answer: it looks much better.

Comment: @Pete: I am still in the process of working out the inner workings of this site, but could you not just have rolled back Denis's change? I understand that now, a revision by one more person will turn the post into CW, which would do Yemon injustice. Or is rolling back also counted as a third edit?

Comment: @Alex: I didn't roll back because I (wrongly) thought that Denis had made some other change in his edit [the comment threw me off a bit].  So I agree that I could have and probably should have.  However, *if* the post becomes CW, which hasn't happened yet, I would hesitate to call it "injustice".  After all, this is a Q&A site, he asked a question, and he has already received an excellent answer.  That's justice, right?  

Comment: Maybe you are right. The CW-tag seems to carry the slight stigma of "you don't deserve getting reputation points for this post", and I suppose the rationale behind the automatism I mentioned is that if four people had to edit the post then it wasn't good enough to earn the posted points. But I agree of course, that the main point of the site is to get answers and share our knowledge. Thank you for your complement on my answer!

Comment: nice question ! 

Comment: PS I can send you a file of Serre's book 

Comment: @AlexanderChervov I've managed to get a copy. Thanks anyway for the offer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The groups you are interested in are sometimes called false Tate extensions in number theorists' jargon. They are Galois groups of the Galois closures of extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining the $p^n$-th roots of a $p$-th power free element. The irreducible representations are very explicitly described in [Vladimir Dokchitser's PhD thesis](http://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~vd209/phdweb.ps), beginning of chapter 3.

Alternatively, the characters, together with their values, are easy to compute using a procedure described in Serre's Linear representation book, part II, Section 8.2. He explains how to obtain all the irreducible characters of any group that is a semi-direct product when the normal subgroup is abelian. Note that the character of an induced representation is easy to compute in terms of the original character and the coset-action.

And of course one more remark: for any given $p$ and $n$, MAGMA will just give you the character table.

Edit: Since you seem unsure, how to ask a computer for the character table, here is MAGMA code as an example. You will easily adopt it to any other package that handles character tables:

```
p:=3; n:=2;
Z:=Integers();
gl:=GL(2,quo<Z|p^n*Z>);
pr:=PrimitiveRoot(p^n);

G:=sub<gl|gl![[1,1],[0,1]],gl![[pr,0],[0,1]]>;
CharacterTable(G);
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. I tried to make it clear in the question that I am *aware* you can work out the characters by inducing up from the abelian normal subgroup (you have a small *Fingerfehler* there) but that, since I don't do this kind of thing as part of my day-to-day teaching or research, I'd be slow and unreliable at it. Your link was helpful and I will also check out Serre's book; but given that knowing the full character table is only the start of the computation I wish to do, perhaps MAGMA is the way to go for me.

Comment: So you did. Sorry, I only skim-read your post before I enthusiastically started typing :) At any rate, Vladimir Dokchitser should do 3 for you and the magma code will do 2.

Comment: (Somewhat amusingly, my library appears not to have the GTM copy of Serre's book, but it does have the French original. Alors je n'ai pas reussi d'echapper la langue francaise...)